# c# sql and loop while

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, while-loop

I try to read all the fields of a column (second column -link-) in my database. I find this example, but I can't manage to read one column of `varchar` type:

```
SQLConnection.Open();

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT link  FROM shop", SQLConnection))
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{2}",reader.GetString(2));
    }
}
```

I've got this error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

and I don't understand why...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM shop`, cause you're getting the second column with `reader.GetString(2)`

Comment: I get this error:
> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
Console.WriteLine("{2}",reader.GetString(2));
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}",reader.GetString(0));
```

since 1.)the [composite formatting feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) uses  **zero-based** indexed placeholders and 2.) you are selecting just one field from the table, so the only index is 0.